# stop ScrollView from scrolling

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-scrollview

I want to stop a ScrollView from scrolling in React Native. I don't want to completely disable it, I just want it to stop scrolling at a specific point, so that I can scroll it again afterwards.

Since the scrolling momentum still persists afterwards, I can't simply disable it when a certain condition is met, so the following code does not work.

```
    <ScrollView
        onScroll={e => {
            if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 500) {
                setStopScroll(true)
            }
        }}
        scrollEnabled={!stopScroll}
    />
```

I omitted the part in which is enabled the scroll view again to continue scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `snapToOffsets`. This takes an array of positions where you want it to stop. After it stops, if you scroll again, it will stop at the next offset. Also make sure `snapToEnd` is set to `false`.

```
<ScrollView
 snapToOffsets={[100,500,800]}
 decelerationRate="fast"
 snapToEnd={false}
 snapToStart={false}
 disableIntervalMomentum={true}
 onScroll={onScroll}
>
 ... your code here
</ScrollView>
```